# How to pass as argument into another method in Flask Framework

Tags: python, flask

How to use "thread_ts" variable from def hi() method and pass it as an argument into
def message_actions() method , If I put as def message_actions(thread_ts): getting missing 1 required positional argument

```
@slack_events_adapter.on("message")
def hi(request_data):
    global channel
    #global thread_ts   # How to not use this global variable and pass it as argument
    if (request_data["event"]["text"].lower() == "hi") or (request_data["event"]["text"].lower() == "hello") or (request_data["event"]["text"].lower() == "hey") and request_data["event"]["type"] == "message":
        print(request_data)
        channel = request_data[ "event" ][ "channel" ],
        channel = channel[ 0 ]
        
        thread_ts = request_data[ "event" ][ "ts" ],
        print("first time", thread_ts)
        user_name = request_data[ "event" ][ "user" ]
        print("User id when hi: " + user_name)
        user_threads_info[ user_name ] = [ ]
        send_options_to_user(slack_client, channel, thread_ts)
    return make_response("", 200)

@app.route("/slack/message_actions", methods=[ "POST" ])
def message_actions(thread_ts):
 if form_json[ "type" ] == "view_submission" and "sth" in form_json[ "view" ][ "callback_id" ]:
        
        send_msg_to_userview(slack_client, channel, thread_ts, user_name)

def send_msg_to_userview(slack_client,channel,thread_ts,user_name):
    placeorder[2]["elements"][0]["text"] = "The selected scenario is *{}* in *{}* environment, Please cilck on above button to place an order".format(user_threads_info[user_name]["fulfillment_value"], user_threads_info[ user_name ][ "environment_value" ] )

 
    slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage",
                          channel=channel,
                          thread_ts=thread_ts,
                          text=""
                          blocks=placeorder
                          )
```

Error Output

```
  File "C:\Users\A603\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: message_actions() missing 1 required positional argument: 'thread_ts'
```

Getting unresolved reference 'thread_ts'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`message_actions` seems to be view function.

If `message_actions` is view function, I guess this error occurs because you don't set `<thread_ts>` label in URL when you register message_actions.

Bad:

```
app = Flask()
app.add_url_rule('/foo/bar', view_func=message_actions) # TypeError: message_actions() missing 1 required positional argument: 'thread_ts'
```

Good:

```
app = Flask()
app.add_url_rule('/foo/bar/<thread_ts>', view_func=message_actions)
```

Comment: my bad i missed pasting it , edited my question now . can you check and help

Comment: As NavaneethaKrishnan's code `message_actions` function should take `thread_ts` argument. If you set a label(`<thread_ts>`) in your URL for view function, the label name argument is passed to view function(`message_actions`). For more details: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules

Comment: If `thread_ts` is passed from JSON as `message_ts` (guessed from image L174-L176), you don't need pass `thread_ts` from URL. (not need `<thread_ts>` label and `message_actions`'s argument)

Comment: yes thread_ts is passed from JSON , so any other way to use thread_ts from def hi(request_data) method into def message_actions()  apart from using global

Comment: I understood your question and I think passing variables to other function by not using global variable is difficult in this case. Because `message_actions` and `hi` is called by different requests so they can't reference local variables each other. If you want to share state(`thread_ts` in this case) between each requests, You need to save/load state to memory(global variable, class) or file or database.

Answer (score 0):

In your `message_actions` function, you are passing thread_ts. This should be passed from the URL.

```
@app.route("/slack/message_actions/<thread_ts>", methods=[ "POST" ])
def message_actions(thread_ts):
```

If you don't want to show thread_ts in the URL, then you can make a `POST` request, or you can pass through `Session`. In those cases, you should not pass the `thread_ts` to your function.